# Using UISearchDisplayController in a child controller

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I made a tabbed controller where the tabs are on top. Underneath the tabs I have a subview which will contain a tableViewController as a child controller.

The tableViewController has a searchBar and a UISearchDisplayController. The problem is, when the search is activated, the UISearchDisplayController jutts out above the frame of the tableView and covers a bit of the tabs.

I believe this is caused by the SearchBar expanding itself on top to cover up the navigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but, why are you using a search display controller?
In this case is easier if you use **just a tableView with a searchBar** as well as your tab.
Then you can develop the same behaviour of the `searchDisplayController`.

There are developers that **have never used** the `searchDisplayController`. In general i use that just when i have a tableViewController within so just a `tableView` and a `searchBar`. But in your case, i would not use that. Take your life easier trust me ;)